# Returning null instead of an array

Tags: php, arrays, null

I have a cart class that returns the products in a users cart

`cart.class.php`

```
    public static function getItems()
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION["cart"]["products"]))
        {
            return array(); 
        }
        else
        {
            return $_SESSION["cart"]["products"];
        }
    }
```

This is the code to get the cart and display it on the page

```
if($action == "getCart")
{       
    echo json_encode(Cart::getItems());

    exit;
}
```

When I'm testing the code on my localhost, it returns `[]` (Empty) but on my website it returns `null`. What have I done wrong?

Comment: have you declared session_start() anywhere?

Comment: Which function returns `null`? `getItems()` or the `json_encode()`?

Comment: Easy-one: you face a session problem. On website, u got a session but null value... on localhost, u have no session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return empty($_SESSION["cart"]["products"]) 
     ? array() 
     : $_SESSION["cart"]["products"];
```

That way, if `$_SESSION["cart"]["products"]` is `null`, you'll still get an empty array.